# Using /setblock, how do I set a command block with a prefilled command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Using `/setblock`, I'd like to set a command block with a command already pre-filled inside of it.

My current code looks like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
setblock <x> <y> <z> command_block {TileEntityData:{Command:"testfor @p[_=1]"}}
```

What's wrong with it, and what do I need to change?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will need to do two things:

- Firstly, there are two other parts to [the `/setblock` command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#setblock) that need to be present; the datavalue, and the method of handling the existing block, if any.
- Secondly, the data tag at the end should just be `{Command: "testfor @p[_=1]"}`, without the TileEntityData bit.

Thus, the resulting command should be along the lines of

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> command_block 0 replace {Command:"testfor @p[_=1]"}
```

As proof, here's a shot of me using that command:

[image: Typing the command]

And here's the result:

[image: The resulting command block]

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/setblock <x> <y> <z> command_block{Command:"..."}`