# How to set a command block with a command inside using a worldedit command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-worldedit

I’ve been making a server, and I can’t get the worldprotect mod to do block-break deny, so I’ve been trying to set a lot of command blocks manually, and then I got lazy. I’ve been trying to find an answer for this ever since. Here is my command:

```
//set command_block {Command:"/gamemode adventure @p"}
```

When I try to place it, it gets placed but the command is not in the command blocks. It shows this message:  [image: the last 2 purple sentences and the last 2 red sentences.]

So, if there is a way to fix this, please tell me the command. Thanks!

Comment: WE's `//set` doesn't support these tags. And what's the point in having 1000s of command blocks with the same command? Why don't you use [setblock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148668/how-to-set-a-command-block-with-a-command-inside-using-the-setblock-command)?

Comment: when i used the setblock command, /setblock command_block {Command:"/gamemode adventure @p"}, it tells me that "command_block is not a valid number"

Comment: That's because you forgot the coordinates. And you can just use `/fill`. I don't really see your problem. You're probably trying it a harder way than you have to. Worldedit is for more complicated things and for bigger areas than Vanilla allows, you don't need it for such a simple thing.

Comment: I recommend you ask another question but explain what you want to do/prevent and include what you have tried.  A bigger picture kind of question.  This way people can suggest alternative solutions.I don't know what you are trying to do but I can almost assure you there is a better solution then 1000's of command blocks.

Comment: Your [setblock command](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/setblock) is missing coordinates and needs to specify dataValue and oldBlockHandling in order to specify dataTag information.  Like this: `/setblock ~ ~ ~ command_block 0 replace {Command:"gamemode adventure @p"}`.

Answer (score 0):

WE doesn't support that kind of argument.

Use the /fill command, which goes like this:

> /fill [x1] [y1] [z1] [x2] [y2] [z2] [block] [data value] [oldBlockHandling] [data tag]

Say you wanted to fill 100x1x100, you would do something like this:

> /fill ~ ~ ~ ~100 ~ ~100 command_block 0 replace {Command:"/gamemode adventure @p"}

Note the ~ means relative coordinates.

But a more logical thing to do would be to set a single command block with this command:

> /gamemode adventure @a[r=100]

This would target any player withing a radius of 100 blocks.

Comment: Your [fill command syntax](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Commands/fill) is incorrect.  If you execute your command it will result in an error: _'{Command:"/gamemode' is not a state for block minecraft:command_block_.  This is because you need to specify dataValue and oldBlockHandling in order to specify dataTag information.  Like this: `/fill ~ ~ ~ ~100 ~ ~100 command_block 0 replace {Command:"gamemode adventure @p"}`.

Comment: Indeed you are correct, editing to fix it