# How do you replace with a command block with command in command block?

Tags: minecraft-commands

I'm trying to update a maps command blocks to 1.13. I found a spot where it replaces a block with a command block, and the command block needs a command already in it. How do I replace a block with a command block with a command in it? This is what I got so far. `/setblock 106 83 159 command_block replace {Command:/scoreboard players test EnderEnterprises Money 750}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a command block with a command inside using the setblock command](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148668/how-to-set-a-command-block-with-a-command-inside-using-the-setblock-command)

Answer (score 2):

In 1.13 the NBT needs to be attached directly to the item or block. So the correct formatting would be:

```
/setblock 106 83 159 command_block {Command:”/scoreboard players test EnderEnterprises Money 750”} replace
```

Comment: If this helped please accept it by clicking the tick next to the awnser.