# Using /setblock to get a command block with a command inside?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

I'm trying to use command blocks for my next creation, but I'm making it so that command blocks make it for me when I press a button. However, I need to have a command that once placed in a command block, it will place another command block with a command already in it (when given a redstone signal, that is).

I'm on Education Edition, so only the Bedrock Edition type of command style will work -  Java Edition won't. I have looked for a command that does this, but I can not find one.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.

[It is only possible on Java Edition where there are NBT tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/148678/188492) and it would be like this:

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> command_block 0 replace {Command:"<command>"}
```